# HorizontalScrollView keep track of current selection

Tags: android

I have a HorizontalScrollView that shows three dates at once and snaps to the date in the middle when you lift your finger. Currently the dates are saved in an LinkedList.

The list has to be dynamic, means that when I scroll to the right, it has to reload the next dates on the right and delete some of the dates on the left. The problem is, I don't know how to create a link between my LinkedList and the ScrollView.

[Here is a link to how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXi7K.png)

Its my first post, so please excuse me if I'm not specific enough.

EDIT: Okay, I found the answer: [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) offers exactly what I want.

Comment: you might want to answer your own question. This helps other users to see there is a resolution to this issue.

Comment: Had to wait 8 Hours due to my small reputation ; ), so I edited and forgot the rest. As you wish!

Comment: oh, I always forget about that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the OP: [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) in combination with a custom Adapter solved my Problem.